# How to get current product id and quantity on view.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to know how to get current product id and quantity on view.phtml.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$id = $product->getId();
$qty = $product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

Comment: I mean can you tell me how to get current product id to own ProductController